# How i can get the current URL inside my list Display form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, development, list-form, aspx, display-form

I edited my display form for a cusotm list using sharepoint designer, and i added the following link, which reference the create form inside another list:-

```
<a href='/sites/****/Lists/Details/NewForm.aspx?Source=&RootFolder=' > + Add New Details</a>
```

but i am not sure how i can get the URL for the current display form (which contain the item ID `/Lists/Device/DispForm.aspx?ID=15`)and add it to the `Source=` parameter inside the above link? so the above link will be as follow `<a href='/sites/****/Lists/Details/NewForm.aspx?Source=/sites/****/Lists/Device/DispForm.aspx?ID=15&RootFolder=' > + Add New Details</a>` so when users add the item inside the external create form, they will be redirected to the display form again?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you need a way to do it in aspx directly since you didnt mention, but you could do it in jQuery quite easily.

First add a class to your link ->

```
<a href='/sites/****/Lists/Details/NewForm.aspx?Source=' class='addDetails'> + Add New Details</a>
```

Then you retrieve href using jQuery and you save it in a var ->

```
var initialHref = $(".addDetails").attr('href');
```

After that you can take the current url location like this ->

```
var currentLocation = window.location.href
```

And finally you put them together

```
$(".addDetails").attr('href', initialHref + currentLocation);
```

It will give you the entire link appended to Source (starting with https), but if you dont want that you could probably split the var (using string.split vanilla js) https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp